# Returning errors from Blazor Server Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'd like to return a standard HTTP error from Blazor Server Page when a parameter does not meet certain requirements or the entity it represents is not found:

```
@page "/feed/{FeedId}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string FeedId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // If Blazor only would support Regex constraints

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(@"^\d{8}$", FeedId))
            // How do you return a 400 to the browser?
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       // FeedId matches the required format but the entity is not in the database
       var feed = await dbContext.Feeds.FindAsync(feedId);

       if(feed == null)
         // return 404
    }
}
```

I haven't found a solution for this so far. Something as fundamental as this should be possible right?

Comment: I don't think you can, because the way blazor works. It works with SignalR to communicate between the server and the client via the WebSockets protocol. So is not using HTTP protocol.

Comment: @DA I know but even then there's an initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

I have a notfound page I use to navigate to when the object was not found using the build in

> NavigationManager

```
@page "/notfound"
<div>
<h1>Page not found</h1>
<p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
</div>
```

Calling the `NavigationManger`

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

if(feed == null) {
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo("notfound");
}
```

Maybe there are other options depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As DA said, the blazor is single-page application which couldn't directly return 404 status code to the client side.

If you want to directly return the 404 or 400 staus codes, one possible way is redirect to the web api and return the 404 or 400 error.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("notfound")]
    public IActionResult NotFoundError()
    {
        return NotFound("Resource not found"); // 404
    }

    [HttpGet("badrequest")]
    public IActionResult BadRequestError()
    {
        return BadRequest("Bad request"); // 400
    }
}
```

Redirect codes:

```
    NavManager.NavigateTo("/api/error/notfound", forceLoad: true);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Of course this wouldn't work in Razor WASM  but I was referring to Blazor Server.  The new SSR Streaming Mode in .NET 8 to be precise: https://chrissainty.com/blazor-in-dotnet-8-server-side-and-streaming-rendering/

Comment: .NET 8 is still in preview.  But I still don't understand you want to return the 404 error inside the blazor server app.

Comment: The initial page load would be an ordinary HTTP request which I want to fail with a standard HTTP status code if the root component is unable to fetch required data. Is that really so hard to imagine? (no sarcasm or offense)

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Did you ever find a solution to this? My attempts show it's not possible in static server rendering